# React Native Fetch works only on second click

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch

I do app on React Native. The problem is next :

OnPress some element i am trying make request to my server and log answer.

When I click button first time - my log do not show anything , but on second click I see response in the console.

```
import React from 'react'

import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput ,  TouchableNativeFeedback      , AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import * as pageActions from '../action/index'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

import api from '../api'


class Login extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
  loginAttempt : false,
  email : 'admin@mail.ru',
  password : 'password',
  token : ''
}
}

 loginAttempt() {
  let email = this.state.email;
  let password = this.state.password;
  api.login(email,password)
 }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <TextInput
        placeholder="Email"
      style={{height: 50, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
      onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({email : value})}
    />
    <TextInput
      placeholder="Password"
      style={{height: 50, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
      onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({password : value})}
    />
    <TouchableNativeFeedback
      style={!this.state.loginAttempt ? {'opacity' : 1} : {'opacity' : 0}}
      onPress={() => this.loginAttempt()}>
      <View>
        <Text>Try login</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableNativeFeedback>
  </View>
   )
   }
  }

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center'
   }
  }
 )
```

My fetch function

```
login(email,password, callback) {

 const API_HEADERS = {
  'Accept' : `application/json`,
  'Content-Type' : `application/json`
  };


let user = {};
user.email = email;
user.password = password;


fetch(`http://myIp:3000/auth/login`, {
  method : 'post',
  headers : API_HEADERS,
  body : JSON.stringify(user)
})
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    } else {
      alert(`Wrong data`)
    }
  })
  .then((responseData) => {
    console.log(responseData)
  })
```

}

Also wanna add that I using Genymotion as android emul.Another strange thing is that when I press my button first time - nothing happens,but when i press Reload JS , before the component will be unmount , I see my responceData in a console

Comment: I'm having this problem, did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You should update state, when promise resolved.

```
.then((responseData) => {
     this.setState({
       token: responseData.token
     });
   })
```

Use catch method:

```
.then().catch(e => console.log("error: ", e))
```

Also, where is your alert function? react-native has Alert module.

```
Alert.alert('any message text');
```

---

article about [fetch](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/)

and this is [article](https://dzone.com/articles/make-http-requests-in-ios-with-react-native) using fetch in react-native

Answer (score 1):

> Another strange thing is that when I press my button first time

This is very like related to focus. 
Try setting  `keyboardShouldPersistTaps = true` for `TouchableNativeFeedback`